# How do I count distinct to exclude a value?

Tags: sql, count, distinct

Below is the different scales in a POS system. I am trying to count the number of distinct scales that are not 'MANUAL WT'.

This is what I have, but it is returning 2 and not 6.
count (distinct (case when d.SCALE_IN_ID != 'MANUAL WT' then 1 else 0 end)) as Num_Scale

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
select count(distinct case when scale_in_id <> 'MANUAL WT' then scale_in_id end) cnt
from mytable
```

The problem with your original query is that the `case` expression turns values to either `0` and `1`, and then the aggregate function computes how many distinct values are returned: since values are all `0`s or `1`s, there are only two distinct values (or one in edge cases): hence the result that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `WHERE` clause will do:

```
select count(distinct scale_in_id) Num_Scale
from tablename
where scale_in_id <> 'MANUAL WT'
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that you want to exclude may be replaced by `NULL`. `Count` excludes `NULL`:

```
select count(distinct case when scale_in_id <> 'MANUAL WT' then scale_in_id else NULL end) cnt
from mytable
```